# How can I handle popup error allerts generated by called libraries in Python?

Tags: python, winapi, error-handling, popup, swig

I have a Python application that calls an external library (swig wrapper on a dll) to initialize a camera. If the camera isn't there the external library generates an error, which I can catch and handle programmatically, but it also generates a popup window which needs to be closed before the program can continue.

I need to either prevent the popup from occurring, or programmatically close the popup. Are either of these options possible from within python?

The final product needs to be able to run autonomously.

Thank you!

Comment: What library is your python program using to create the program's user interface? QT? GTK? Javascript/HTML/WSGI? Do you have access to the code that creates the popup?

Comment: Right now there is no graphical user interface, just command line interaction on windows7. 

The documentation says the thrown exception is a java exception. I think the code that throws the exception is open-source so I should be able to find it and view it, but I don't want to change it.

Comment: You are dealing with third party software, that's not always easy. Is there software that currently handles the camera, something from the manufacturer maybe? It could be that if the camera is activated via your library call, it wakes up the existing software which pops up a window. If your code doesn't invoke the popup window, the problem isn't really related to your code... You could try uninstalling any existing camera-handling software (but NOT the drivers). Does the title or content of the popup window say anything about what is running it?

Comment: The answer looks good but can you add enough detail for anyone later to reproduce the issue into the question?

Answer (score 0):

This feels very dirty... I launch a subprocess that looks for the warning window before I try to initialize it. Then, if the camera fails to initalize and throws the popup warning, I recognize it and kill it using win32gui.

Relevant code in the main function:

```
try:
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "-m", "kill_warning"])
    init_camera()
except NoCamera:
    print("No camera found!")
```

and the `kill_warning` code (try once a second for ten seconds):

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, r'TIS Initialisation Error')
        win32gui.PostMessage(handle, win32con.WM_CLOSE,0,0)
        time.sleep(1)
```

If something strikes you as dangerous with this method, please let me know!